# Delegating access in Outlook- why do both users need to have the same version?

Tags: exchange, outlook, exchange-2013

According to Microsoft "[You and the delegate must use the same version of Outlook.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Allow-someone-else-to-manage-your-mail-and-calendar-41c40c04-3bd1-4d22-963a-28eafec25926?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)"

Why is this? Is this because your version of Outlook might have features the delegates version doesn't support? Do you get an error if you try to setup delegation between users with different Outlook versions?

What happens on the back end when delegation is setup? Does exchange check your client version?

Comment: AFAIK it's because of differences in the Outlook clients and how they handle calendar entries. At the back-end it's just an AD attribute set, there is no checking. But not sure why you wouldn't want to follow the advice?

Comment: Note that any user that has a license for an Exchange mailbox also has a license to install the appropriate version of Outlook on their computer. You should definitely work hard to make sure all of your users have the same version of Outlook, and also Office and even Windows, as much as possible.

Comment: Don't have different clients just curious about this.  So are mailbox's on the server bound to a specific version? If I have Exchange online (which I think is Exchange 2013?) can I delegate a mailbox to an outlook 2010 client?

Comment: There is no blocking by default and all supported versions of Outlook can connect to Exchange. You can setup blocking on a CAS or mailbox basis - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335207%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that is set is the attribute MSExchDelegateListLink, there is no enforcing of using the same Outlook version.

As an admin you may want to force users to use the same Outlook version by configuring 'Outlook client blocking' - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335207%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396